# Sending out a message reliably

Tags: android, events, methods, timing

I have a handler.postDelayed that loops every x seconds, I want to send a sort of message/event/broadcast so that a method starts only when it receives the broadcast.

I tried broadcast hit but it has a latency. I need it to be super accurate. Is there anything that does this?

Comment: Super accurate is relative and if that is really needed then android might not be the platform for you. You will need something like a real-time OS. Please describe your use case.

Comment: I have a metronome beeping, and a set of rhythms that have to play when a metronome hit happens.

Comment: I think Android accuracy should be able to hit that.

Comment: Then what should I use? I've been trying to look for something that does this, I've even tried a few things but nothing seems to be what I need: a simple message sends every once in a while and a reciever that does something when it gets that message.

Comment: I am not 100% on which looping mechanism you should use, but android has "high performance" audio support documented here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-audio-high-performance/tree/master/aaudio

Comment: Note! I have not used the high performance android audio api's so I will not be able to help in that area either, but that is a reference that might help. Please post back if it works for you.